# Coldfusion Application.cfc & Application.cfm in the same folder

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc, application.cfm

I am modifying an existing web application which has been coded in Coldfusion. In the existing code, a large portion of the folders contain an Application.cfm file which sets the Application variables

However, part of my modification to these apps requires me to use the Application.cfc rather then the existing .cfm file.

Is there any potiential problems of having both of these files in the same directory? Or will Coldfusion default to using one over the other (or will it run both?)

Thanks,
Steven

**EDIT**

Just to shine some more light onto this. I am integrating a new centralized login system, but a caveat of this is that it must have a fall back login (in case of downtimne for login system). That is why i dont want to blow out the old code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is an Application.cfc file ColdFusion will use that.  If you have both, Application.cfm will be ignored.

Comment: Plus you should be able to move everything over from application.cfm to application.cfc without a problem.

Comment: In a mixed Application.cfc, Application.cfm environment, be sure you understand the order they are loaded very well or you'll find yourself with odd results. See my related answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749637/coldfusion-application-cfm-and-affected-files/5799442#5799442